# Category filter in custom admin grid in tab not working

Tags: magento-2.1, filter, custom-grid

I have created a grid under tab[image: Grid created by block]

Everything is working fine except the category filter,data under category column is shown using renderer. When I change the value in dropdown , the loader just keeps loading.
Please help if any one knows what I have skipped.

Comment: can you please add the code, how you added category dropdown

Comment: //adding category column to grid    $this->addColumn(
            'category_ids',
            [
                'header' => __('Category'),
                'index' => 'name',
                'class' => 'xxx',
                'width' => '50px',
                'type' => 'options',
                'options' => $this->getCategoryOptions(),
                'renderer'=> 'Vendor\Assigncategory\Block\Adminhtml\Assigncategory\Edit\Tab\Renderer\Category',
            ]
        );

Answer (score -1):

I have facing same issue for grid.

I have found the solution. It's work fine for me.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    if(!empty($this->getCustomerGroupIds())) {
        $customerGroupIds = $this->getCustomerGroupIds();
    } else if(!empty($this->backendSession->getCustomerGroupIds())) {
        $customerGroupIds = $this->backendSession->getCustomerGroupIds();
        $this->backendSession->unsCustomerGroupIds();
    } else {
        $customerGroupIds = [];
    }


    $customerCollections = $this->customerFactory->create();
    $customerCollections->joinAttribute('country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');
    $customerCollections->addFilterToMap('country_id', 'customer_address.country_id');
    $customerCollections->addFieldToFilter('group_id', ['in' => $customerGroupIds]);
    $this->setCollection($customerCollections);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
{
    // Set custom filter for in customer flag        
    if ($column->getId() == 'customer_ids') {
        $customerIds = $this->_getSelectedCustomers();
        if (empty($customerIds)) {
            $customerIds = 0;
        }
        if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $customerIds]);
        } else {
            if ($customerIds) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => $customerIds]);
            }
        }
    } else if($column->getId() == 'country_id') {
        $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('country_id', ['eq' => $column->getFilter()->getValue()]);            
    } else {
        parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I have done it for customer country_id.

Hope its help you. Let me know if you have any query.